What is the correct way of automating a slideshow to prevent too many rerenders in React
I am sure I am just I am just being a bit daft, but for the life of me I can not figure this out. I am fetching some data (id, title, slides, etc) from an api route using swr which went swimmingly. I was planning on taking my data.slides and creating a simple  animated slideshow, just advance to the next slide every 5 seconds. I thought I could just use a useEffect and setInterval to progress the slides, but eventually (after 23), I hit "Too many re-renders".
    const { slideshow, isError, isLoading } = useSlideshow();
    const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setCurrentSlide((prevSlide) => (prevSlide + 1) % (slides?.length ?? 0));
            console.log("currentSlide", currentSlide);
        }, 500);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [slides.length, currentSlide]);

I am sure I am missing something, but I am at a loss. What would be the away to go about this to prevent the excessive re-renders while still progressing through the slides?

The useEffect hook enqueues a currentSlide state update and uses the currentSlide state as a dependency. This means the effect runs on the initial render cycle, and then again any time any dependency updates, and since the effect updates the currentSlide state each time, it triggers a component rerender and runs the effect again, e.g. creates a render loop.
It seems the problem is just the console log of the "current" state, move this into a separate effect so the effect of logging the current currentSlide state value is separate from instantiating an maintaining the slider show interval.
const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setCurrentSlide((prevSlide) => (prevSlide + 1) % (slides?.length ?? 0));
  }, 5000); // 5000ms => 5s

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [slides.length]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("currentSlide", currentSlide);
}, [currentSlide]);

